# How to select an entire row and column after finding a cell?

Tags: c#, excel

After searching for a value in an Excel range I need to select only the entire row and then get each value found in the columns of the row.

```
xlRange = xlWorksheet.Range[rangeStart, rangeStop];

var xlCell = xlRange.Find
    (
        valueToFind
        , xlRange.Range[rangeStart]
        , Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues
        , Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole
        , Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns
        , Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext
        , false
    );
```

Going from the `xlCell.get_Address()` I need to get only the full row and maybe the full column of that found cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the full row or column of `xlCell` and their values, you can use this code:

```
var row = xlCell.EntireRow;
object[,] rowValues = row.Value2;

var col = xlCell.EntireColumn;
object[,] colValues = col.Value2;
```

Be aware that these values are pretty big arrays with the contents of the whole worksheet. If you want only the relevant ones, the following should to the trick:

```
var cells = xlWorksheet.Cells;
var used = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

var rowCellFirst = cells[row.Row, 1];
var rowCellLast = cells[row.Row, used.Column + used.Columns.Count - 1];
object[,] rowValuesUsed = xlWorksheet.Range[rowCellFirst, rowCellLast].Value2;

var colCellFirst = cells[1, col.Column];
var colCellLast = cells[used.Row + used.Rows.Count - 1, col.Column];
object[,] colValuesUsed = xlWorksheet.Range[colCellFirst, colCellLast].Value2;
```